# Wildfly share session between EARs?

Tags: session, jboss, wildfly

I have 2 WAR applications in 2 independent EARs that I want to deploy in a single instance of Wildfly 10/JBoss 7 EAP.  How can I share sessions/authentication between the 2 wars?

Ex:

```
EAR1:
- WAR1
- EJB
- libs


EAR2:
- WAR2
- libs
```

To be clear, I would like the user to login and authenticate via WAR1, and have that session object available when he accesses WAR2 so that he does not need to log back into the system.

How can I accomplish this?  I cannot find documentation relating to what configuration is required to achieve this.

Comment: Although HttpSession objects often seem to go hand in hand with authentication, there is often no specific relationship between them. Do you really want to share the actual HttpSession between WARs? You're asking for a bunch of class loading problems if you do this.

Comment: @SteveC Actually, my requirement isn't as much to share the HttpSession inasmuch as I need to share the authentication information without creating/implementing an SSO solution.  The only way I can think/imagine how to do that without an SSO solution is to share the session object to transfer that information.  Is there another possibility that I haven't considered?

Comment: You could stuff an encrypted token into a cookie. You may even be able to serialise and encrypt your "authentication information" and fit it into a cookie. But really, integrating something like [KeyCloak](http://www.keycloak.org) is pretty easy.

Comment: @SteveC Funny - that's pretty much what I did as my initial ProofOfConcept, but was asked to see if I couldn't find a way without the extra step.  Hence the question.  From what I can tell quickly, KeyCloak just looks like an SSO solution/IdP solution, isn't it?  What is the difference between KeyCloak and another SSO solution (ex: WSO2, Auth0, Ping, etc)?

Comment: That's right. But it's way less complicated than some of the "big iron" solutions that are around. Security is important and should never be trivialised. Companies with weak application security are the ones that get into the news...

Comment: @SteveC Thanks - I'll add it to my list of options to investigate.  With respect to the HttpSession objects, you did bring up a good point; would both of my WARs need to have access to the same models/classes that are used by the Session object?  Or is the Session abstracted enough by its Interface that as long as I only retrieve attributes that belong to each WAR, I should be ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146813/discussion-between-steve-c-and-eric-b).

Answer (score 2):

If you only need single sign on and session sharing for apps within wildlfy, you don't need any dedicated SSO mechanism - server already has everything you need. First, you need to secure you applications using some existing security-domain via `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml`. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>   
    <security-domain>my-sec-domain</security-domain>    
</jboss-web>
```

Next you need to enable SSO handling in Undertow(Jboss/Wildfly web server). You can do it with CLI or by manualy updating the corresponding config. Cli command(for standalone mode):

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/setting=single-sign-on:add(path=/)
```

Or if you edit the config manually, add `<single-sign-on path="/" />` to undertow config like so:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
   <buffer-cache name="default"/>
   <server name="default-server">
    <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp"/>
    <http-listener name="default" max-post-size="20485760" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
       <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
       <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
       <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
       <single-sign-on/>
   </host>
</server>
```

Now we need to enable mechanism for session replication/sharing. In wildfly, it is done using the infinispan subsystem and web cache. You will either need to use `full-ha` configuraiton profile(`standalone-full-ha.xml`) or manualy add that subsystem to your config. Here awe are looking for cache container named `web`. If its there, you should be good to go.
Now when you visit APP-A in your browser, you should get two session cookies JSESSIONID and JSESSIONIDSSO. After switching to APP-B, you should be automatically logged in.
Happy Hacking

Comment: I was trying to get more info/details how that works.  The docs are super thin on it.  If I have APP-A secured by jaas form authentication do you know if/how I can use spring security in APP-B  or do they both need to use JAAS?

Comment: SSO is not trivial and many people understand different subjects under this term. Even redhat has  different products that address it- jboss sso, keycloak... You can find more info if you have access to redhat customer portal. If the abovementioned undertow setting does not work, try looking up more info on Saml v2 or give Keycloak a try.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing session between two web application which are part of same EAR is possible, go through [document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/development_guide/class_loading_and_modules#configuring_session_sharing_between_subdeployments_in_enterprise_archives) for more details on this. For single authentication for both web applications, you have to implement SSO. You can implement SSO using [SAML](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/how_to_set_up_sso_with_saml_v2/sso_with_samlv2_deeper_dive) or [Kerberos](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/7.0/how-to-set-up-sso-with-kerberos/how-to-set-up-sso-with-kerberos/). Hope it helps..!!

Comment: SteveC made a valid point above; if I share the session object between two webapps in the same EAR, do I need to ensure that I have all the same models/libraries that are contained in the Session object by both WARs?