# Sharing authentication information between 2 webapps using the Session object?

Tags: spring, spring-security, jaas

This is a bit of a followup to an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44575200/827480) I made on SO looking to share session info between 2 EARs.  Instead, I've rebuilt my EAR to have two webapps running in the same EAR on Wildfly 10.  I've enabled session sharing between the two webapps and can confirm that it is indeed the same session object being used.

My issue is that webapp1 is a legacy JEE app that uses JAAS for authentication and webapp2 is a new Spring Boot/Spring Security app.

My use case is that I need to authenticate/authorize via Webapp1 and have webapp2 recognize that authentication.  There is no authentication in webapp2 - everything has to happen via webapp1.

Right now, the only way I can envision doing this is create a custom filter in my Spring app which does:

```
if( SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null && request.getUserPrincipal() != null ){
    // some mechanism to retrieve the authentication info and set it in the Spring context
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication( new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken( username, etc) )
 }
 else{
    // if no request.getUserPrincipal() object, then redirect to webapp1 login page
 }
```

I'm not exactly sure what mechanism I need to use for the authentication object; I suspect I'll need to query my DB to retrieve the user's roles based on the username in the `getUserPrincipal()` object and add them to a
`PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken()` or something of the sort.

Is there a cleaner mechanism to do this?  Is there a way I can use the JassAuthenticationToken to retrieve information from the existing LoginContext that has already been instantiated by Webapp1?

Is doing it this way via a filter secure?

Comment: have you looked into spring session?

Comment: @redflar3 yes, but Im trying to avoid modifing the legacy webapp if possible.  And the way I would foresee using Spring Session is to modify both to use it with an external session source.  I'm not even sure that my current (ie legacy) session object is serializable.

Comment: @redflar3 I was thinking some more about your suggestion of Spring Session, but the more I thought about it, I didn't see how it would help the issue; I still have 2 different authentication systems that need to authenticate differently.  How would Spring Session help for that?