# ¿How can I share the security and the filter between different wars of the same ear?

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security, jsf-2.2

I have an ear that contains three wars. war1 to use the user login, this works correctly. war2 with app1 and war3 for app2.

What I'm trying to do is share the session and apply the security filter with war2 and war3. As seen in the image. How can I do this?

[image: ear]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand that all three applications are independent and seperated by contexts and do not share any resources and cannot communicate with each other directly. For this you need to use an external authentication service like keycloak. Maybe a singleton EJB present in the EAR as an own module and used by all the wars works, whereby the EJB holds the security state.

In websphere there was an WebsphereApllicationSession or so which allowed to share state between modules but this websphere specific. Such a functionality depends on your application server you use and is not portable.

See the following links for further information but I recommend to use an SSO server such as keycloak.

https://technology.amis.nl/2012/01/18/sharing-session-state-between-jee-web-application-through-weblogic-session-descriptor-of-sharing-enabled/

https://www.google.com/amp/s/thewonggei.wordpress.com/2009/07/22/how-to-share-session-between-web-modules-in-websphere-6-1/amp/

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/178290/why-cant-wars-share-session-info

[Wildfly share session between EARs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575200/wildfly-share-session-between-ears)

https://forum.reportserver.net/viewtopic.php?id=173

https://www.keycloak.org